How can a Maui IOS app access files in the iPhone Dropbox app
I have developed a dot maui app and I would like this app to access the files in the dropbox app on the iPhone.
With dropbox installed you can mark files for use offline, and I would like my app to access these.
Can someone tell me how to do this please.
I have searched the web but can't find anything that directly helps

you have to use the Dropbox API.  You can't just access the Dropbox folder directly

Or you can look for a package that uses UIDocumentPickerViewController - this lets the use select a file from the local device, including any files that have been stored by compatible cloud file providers.

Please consider adding a screenshot to illustrate the issue

So Dropbox confirmed that this is not possible:
"The mobile app is essentially a mobile web viewer for the files, so they aren't located directly on the phone, unless they're marked as available offline. The phone storage used for those files is hidden from the rest of the system, however, so it can't be accessed directly by other apps"
The reason for the question is that I already use the dropbox API and upload and download files. I run the same app on my PC and iPhone ( a benefit of using maui). The PC syncs with Dropbox automatically, but I am having to manually sync to the iPhone which is tedious as there's 30+ GB of files and it would be so nice if I could just mark those files for offline use and have my app access them !!! I am basically writing a shadow dropbox, when it's really already there !
This is where the IOS sandbox system backfires. The only thing I have seen is entitlements which allow the same developer(s) to allow interop between apps, but there is no such provision for other apps.

What is the source of text inside quotes? If there it is posted at some website, please give the link

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Integrations/How-can-a-Maui-iOS-app-access-files-in-the-iPhone-Dropbox-app/m-p/796973#M14168
